Point Cloud Processing Tools on MacOS
I am trying to access the native Point Cloud Processing tools, developed by Lutra Conslting and added to QGIS 3.32 (https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2023/05/30/pointcloud-qgis-processing/).
I have installed 3.36, but the tools do not appear in the processing toolbox.
My mac is running Ventura 13.6 with a 10 core intel i9 processor.
The same problem came up in this post - How can I find the Point Cloud Tools in QGIS 3.34 Mac Version?
According to 'about QGIS' my install includes PDAL version 2.3.0 (shown in screenshot below):

The previous answers and comments seem to suggest the problem is most likely to be with the standalone installer (which I also used) potentially not including PDAL, and then suggest using the OSGeo4W installer (which doesn't work on Macs) or MacPorts. But as far as I can tell a relatively recent version of PDAL is included in my install.
I'm not a computer scientist, and am really hoping to find a solution that doesn't entail using a packets manager (eg MacPorts to tinker with the QGIS install, or Conda to install PDAL).

Saber from Lutra has (mostly) solved my conundrum in an email (as well as creating the Point Cloud tools in the first place).
The problem seems to be that the PDAL library in the standalone installer is out of date (along with other libraries apparently).
The solution is to use the .pkg installer here: https://github.com/opengisch/qgis-conda-builder/releases
Point Cloud Processing tools now appear.
There are a couple of caveats - GRASS tools do not appear in the processing toolbox, and certain .laz files no longer load (I think those that include "full waveform data") where they do load on the standalone install version from the QGIS website (which doesn't support the point cloud tools).

The tools require pdal_wrench which requires PDAL >= 2.5
https://github.com/PDAL/wrench
